# Is there a way to dyamic name log files in java?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm using logback as my logging framework and have a couple of jobs that run the same `main` function with different parameters and would like to create a log file for each job and name the log file with the job's name.

For example, if I had jobs `a,b,c` that all run `MyClass.main()` but with different parameters, then I'd like to see `a-{date}.log, b-{date}.log, c-{date}.log`.

I can achieve the `{date}` part by specifying a `<fileNamePattern>myjob-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>` in my `logback.xml`, but I'm not sure how to (or if it is even possible) create the prefix of the file names dynamically (to be the job's name).

Is there a way to dynamically name logfiles in logback? Is there another logging framework that makes this possible?

As a follow up question, am I just taking a bad approach for having multiple jobs that call the same `main` function with different parameters and wanting a log file named after each job? If so is there a standard/best practice solution for this case?

EDIT: The reason why I want to name each log file after the name of the job is that each job naturally defines a "unit of work" and it is easier for me to find the appropriate log file in case one of the job fails. I could simply use a rolling log file for jobs `a,b,c` but I found it harder for me to look through the logs and pinpoint where each job started and ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically name logfiles in logback?  Is there another logging framework that makes this possible?

I don't believe this is possible using the `out of the box` appenders (`File`, `RollingFile` etc) configured by a standard logback.xml file.  To do what you want, you would need to dynamically create appenders on the fly and assign loggers to different appenders.  Or you would need to invent a new appender that was smart enough to write to multiple files at the same time, based on the logger name.

> am I just taking a bad approach for having multiple jobs that call the same main function with different parameters and wanting a log file named after each job?

The authors of logback address this issue and `slightly discourage` it in the section on [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

> A possible but slightly discouraged approach to differentiate the logging output of one client from another consists of instantiating a new and separate logger for each client. This technique promotes the proliferation of loggers and may increase their management overhead. ... A lighter technique consists of uniquely stamping each log request servicing a given client.

Then they go on to discuss mapped diagnostic contexts as a solution to this problem.  They give an example of a NumberCruncherServer which is crunching numbers, for various clients in various threads simultaneously.  By setting the mapped diagnostic context and an appropriate logging pattern it becomes easy to determine which log events originated from which client.  Then you could simply use a `grep` tool to separate logging events of interest into a separate file for detailed analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I would use you own logging.

```
public static PrintWriter getLogerFor(String prefix) {
     SimpleDatFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     String filename= prefix + sdf.format(new Date());
     return new PrintWriter(filename, true); // auto flush.
}
```

You can write a simple LRU cache e.g. with LinkedHashMap to reuse the PrintWriters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

First you have to familiarize your self with these 2 concepts: Logger and Appender. Generally speaking, your code obtains a Logger, and invoke logging method such as debug(), warn(), info() etc. Logger has Appender attached to it, and Appender presents the logging information to the user according to the configuration set to it.

Once you're familiar, what you need to do is to dynamically create a FileAppender with a different file name for each different job type, and attach it to your Logger.

I suggest you spend some time with logback manual if none of above make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the logback discriminators, as discriminators' keys can be used in the `<FileNamePattern>` tag. I can think of two options:

**Option One:**

You can use the [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) discriminator to implement your logging separation, you'll need to set a distinct value from each job using `MDC.put();`

Once you've done that your appender on logback configuration would look something like:

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
        <key>jobName</key> <!-- the key you used with MDC.put() -->
        <defaultValue>none</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="jobsLogs-${jobName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <FileNamePattern>${jobName}.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
                .
                .
                .
            </rollingPolicy>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>...</Pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

**Option Two:**

Implement your own discriminator -implementing `ch.qos.logback.core.sift.Discriminator`-, to discriminate based on the thread name. Would look something like this:

```
public class ThreadNameDiscriminator implements Discriminator<ILoggingEvent> {

    private final String THREAD_NAME_KEY = "threadName";

    @Override
    public String getDiscriminatingValue(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
    return THREAD_NAME_KEY;
    }

    // implementation for more methods
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The logging appender would look like option one with the discriminator class being `ThreadNameDiscriminator` and the key being `threadName`. In this option there is no need to set a value to the MDC from your jobs, hence, no modification on them is required.